# How to plot a 2D triangular lattice

Tags: plotting, lattices

I wonder if I could plot the Fig1.(a) in Physical Review A 87, 063421 (2013), a triangular lattice in MMA. I undetstand that those atoms and interactions can be added by Adobe AI after obtaining the eps by MMA.

Actually I've tried by defining a piecewise function and Plot3D, but it seems to be wierd and the figure is uncontinuous at the boundaries.

Thanks a lot.
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Please share the code. What is the formula for the potential? Not providing necessary information won't help you here.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.6687.pdf

Comment: The point is that I gave the reference clearly enough, and I would be able to plot if I know the potential. Thanks anyway.

Comment: In this article there is nothing about the potential. They write under the FIG.1:  "Schematic diagram of the smallest triangular cell of three atoms (a, b and c) trapped in a two-dimensional triangular lattice".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Show[
 Plot3D[
  Evaluate@Sum[
    -Exp[-(((x - xo + yo/2)^2 + (y - yo Sqrt[3]/2)^2)/(2/25))]
    , {yo, -1, 6}
    , {xo, Round[yo/2] - 1, 4 + Round[yo/2]}
    ]
  , {x, -0.2, 3.2}
  , {y, -0.5, 2.5}
  , Mesh -> None
  , PlotPoints -> 100
  , PlotRange -> {-1, 1}
  , BoxRatios -> {3.4, 3, 2}
  ],
 Graphics3D[
  {
   Blue, Sphere[{1, Sqrt[3]/2 2, -1/2}, .2],
   Purple, Sphere[{3/2, Sqrt[3]/2, -1/2}, .2],
   Green, Sphere[{1/2, Sqrt[3]/2, -1/2}, .2]

   }]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I tried the Cos type, and now I now it's an exponential  trap. Thanks for the nice answer.